# How to use Anchor, the validation system of sails?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm trying to use Sails, but I can't use the model validation, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

Validations are added to the attributes object on a model. You can find a list of available validations at: [Sails Wiki - Models](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-wiki/blob/0.9/models.md#validations). They are run whenever you are submitting data to be written to a datastore. So on `create` Waterline will validate all the attributes you submit and on `update` it will validate the attributes you are trying to change.

An Example model with validations would look something like:

```js
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    firstName: {
      type: 'string',
      minLength: 3,
      required: true
    },

    lastName: {
      type: 'string',
      minLength: 3,
      required: true
    },

    email: {
      // types can be a validation type and will be converted to a string
      // when saved
      type: 'email',
      required: true
    },

    sex: {
      type: 'string',
      in: ['male', 'female']
    },

    favoriteColor: {
      type: 'string',
      defaultsTo: 'blue'
    },

    age: {
      type: 'integer',
      min: 18
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: For some reason the validation never triggred. I had to change of frameworks. I was an urgent project

Comment: @donnanicolas: does adding `schema: true` to the model helps? BTW what other framework did you choose?